# Ember JS - Link-to states it needs id (ERROR)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, link-to

```
ROUTER.JS
this.route('widgets', function () {
     this.route('widget', {path: '/:widget_id' }, function () {
          this.route('files');
          this.route('agreements');
     }
});

HBS FILE:
<listGroup.link-to @route="toplevel.settings.widgets.index">Widgets</listGroup.link-to>

WIDGETS ROUTE COMPONENT:
<body.row role="button" {{on "click" (transition-to (if @admin "toplevel.widgets.widget" "toplevel.setting.widgets.widget") widget.id)}} as |row|>
```

I have a link-to in a profile settings menu that links to an hbs file that displays a list of widgets (not widgets, but it's proprietary, so for sake of example "widgets").

Each list item in the widgets hbs uses the transition-to helper to transition to a single widget.  There are no issues so far.

When I click on the nav with the original link-to to go back to the list of widgets I get this error:

**"Uncaught (in promise) Error: While generating link to route "toplevel.settings.widgets.widget": You must provide param `widget_id` to `generate`."**

Is the problem in the router.js file or in my link-to?  I know the error states it's the link-to, however it does not error until trying to go back to the list, which does not need a specific id.

Comment: from where do you have the `transition-to` helper? what does it do? does it correctly pass the widget id? This pattern [basically should work](https://ember-twiddle.com/98ef88f850e8ba0f6008337cb221379d?openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2C&route=%2Fwidgets%2F1).

Comment: The transition-to helper is in a component in the Widgets route.  It takes you to a list view of widgets.  When you click on an individual line you are transitioned-to a single widget view.  The error occurs when I try to click on the nav to take me back to the list view.  The list view does not need an ID, but when it attempts to transition to the list of widgets route, it errors saying it needs me to pass an ID.

Comment: can you simplify your example? from what you said this should work as the twiddle I posted demonstrates. can you provide a not-working example, as twittle or as a git repo or exact steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: My Senior developer figured out my issue.  It was a breadcrumb library we are using.  I didn't pass the model to it, so it was erroring out.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was answered in the comments under the question